# compute the integration in R

Tags: r

I compute the cumulative distribution function whose result should lie in [0,1]. The equation for computing the CDF is:

\begin{align}

F= \int_{\hat{a}}^{x}\frac{2}{\hat{b}-\hat{a}} ~\sum \nolimits_{k=0}^{' N-1} C_{k}~\text{cos} \bigg( \big(y - \hat{a} \big) \frac{k \pi}{\hat{b} - \hat{a}}\bigg) ~dy

\end{align}

where

- `Ck` is a vector
- `cos term` is a vector
- length(`ck`) = length(`cos term`) = N.

I am sure the equation is correct, but I am afraid my code is incorrect.

Here is my code:

```
integrand<-function(x,myCk)
{
 (2/(b-a))*(t(myCk)%*%as.matrix(cos((x-hat.a)*uk)))
}

f <- function(x){integrand(x,myCk)}

# define a vectorized version of this function 
fv <- Vectorize(f,"x")

res<-integrate(fv,upper = r,lower = hat.a, subdivisions = 2000)$value
```

`res`returns the cumulative distribution function, and the result can be larger than 1.

1. `myCk`is a vector generated by another function.
2. `hat.a`is the lower bound for integration, and it is negative.
3. `uk`is a vector generated by a function. The length of `uk`equals the length of `myCk`.

I appreciate your advice!

Comment: No Need for ˋtˋ and ˋas.matrixˋ. How is it made sure that the cos term is non-negative?

Comment: the cos term can be negative @Karsten W.

Comment: so how can this integrand be a density?

Comment: The formula is proposed by this paper http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0096300316305252 , and it is equation (14). @Karsten W.

Comment: Maybe the `a` in your integrand function should be `hat.a`. Otherwise, the code looks ok to me. Why do you think the computed result is wrong? Did you do a plot of the integrand?